# Вычислить сумму ряда по формуле Delphi

Tags: delphi, функции, циклы, ряды

Есть условие задачи:

> Написать программу, вычисляющую сумму ряда S(x) с заданной точностью eps для заданного значения аргумента x. 
>   Программа должна вычислить: значение суммы ряда, последнее учтенное в сумме слагаемое, число жтих слагаемых.
>   S(x) = x - x^3/3! + x^5/5! - x^7/7! + ...

Написал код на Delphi, но результат всё равно выводит неправильный:

```
unit SumOfTaylorSin;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  Label1: TLabel;
  Label2: TLabel;
  Label3: TLabel;
  Label4: TLabel;
  Label5: TLabel;
  Label6: TLabel;
  Label7: TLabel;
  eps: TEdit;
  x: TEdit;
  Sum: TEdit;
  Num: TEdit;
  Last: TEdit;
  Count: TButton;
  Reset: TButton;

  procedure CountClick(Sender: TObject);
  procedure ResetClick(Sender: TObject);
private
  { Private declarations }
public
  { Public declarations }
end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  eps_enter: integer; // точность (ввод)
  eps_str : string; // строка для проверки eps
  x_enter: integer; // аргумент (ввод)
  x_str : string; // строка для проверки x
  power_denomin: integer; // знаменатель/степень
  n: integer; // порядковый номер ряда
  e: integer; // проверка на возможность конвертации (bool)
  minus : integer; // значение '-1' для вычисления ряда
  comp : real; // сравнение, порядковый член, который сейчас сравниваем
  sum_: integer; // сумма ряда
  comp_check : real; // вычисление значения следующей дроби для проверки необходимости входить в цикл

implementation

{$R *.dfm}


function Factorial(n: integer): longint; // функция подсчёта факториала
 begin
 if n=0 then Factorial := 1 // если n = 0, то факториал = 1
 else Factorial := n*Factorial(n-1); // в противном случае факториал принимает значение произведения самого себя и функции факториала меньшего на единицу
 end;

function Power(x,y:integer):extended; // функция возведения в степень
begin
if x=0 then Power:=0 // если x = 0, то степень = 0
else if x>0 then Power:=exp(ln(x)*y) // если x > 0, то возводим в степень через exp и lg
else Power:=-exp(ln(abs(x))*y); // если x < 0, то возводим в степень через exp и lg и умножаем на '-1'
end;

procedure TForm1.CountClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  eps_str := eps.Text; // точность eps
  val(eps_str, eps_enter, e); // проверка на ввод данных
  x_str := x.Text; // аргумент x
  val(x_str, x_enter, e); // проверка на ввод данных
  if (e <> 0) then // если проверка не прошла, удаляем содержимое строчек и выводим сообщение об ошибке
  begin
    eps.Text := ''; // очищаем текст с точностью eps
    x.Text := ''; // очищаем текст с аргументом x
    ShowMessage('Ошибка ввода данных! Введите данные снова!');
  end;

  minus := -1; // минус перед слагаемым
  power_denomin := 1; // степень/знаменатель
  n := 1; // порядковый номер
  comp := Trunc(Power(-1, n+1)); // сравниваемая дробь (изначально присваиваем ей 1 (-1 во второй степени))

  while eps_enter < abs(comp_check) do // пока введённая точность меньше следующей сравниваемой дроби
  begin
    comp := minus * (Trunc(Power(x_enter, power_denomin)) / 
Factorial(power_denomin)); // по формуле
    Inc(n); // увеличиваем порядковый номер на единицу
    sum_ := sum_ + Trunc(comp); // суммируем сравниваемую дробь
    power_denomin := power_denomin + 2; // прибавляем двойку к степени двойку
    minus := Trunc(Power(-1, n+1)); // высчитываем минус/плюс
    comp_check := minus * (Trunc(Power(x_enter, power_denomin))/ 
Factorial(power_denomin)); // следующая сравниваемая дробь
  end;

  sum.Text := IntToStr(sum_); // выводим сумму ряда
  Num.Text := IntToStr(n); // число слагаемых
  Last.Text := FloatToStr(comp); // последнее учтённое в сумме слагаемое

end;

procedure TForm1.ResetClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  eps.Text := ''; // очищаем текст с точностью eps
  x.Text := ''; // очищаем текст с аргументом x
  sum.Text := ''; // очищаем вывод суммы ряда
  Num.Text := ''; // очищаем вывод  числа слагаемых
  Last.Text := ''; // очищаем вывод последнего учтённого слагаемого
end;

end.
```

Вопросы:

- В чём ошибка в коде
- Правильно ли выполнено условие

Comment: Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow.  "результат всё равно выводит неправильный" - мы должны угадать, какой результат правильный и какой неправильный?

Comment: При любом вводе точности eps и аргумента x, он выводит сумму ряда 0(sum_), число слагаемых 1(n), последнее слагаемое -1(comp), а должен выводить сумму ряда по формуле, порядковый номер последнего слагаемого и само последнее слагаемое

Comment: лютое форматирование. вы не пробовали комменты от кода отделать ? и зачем в каджой дроби факториал вычислять с самого начала? по сути тут должно быть единственное поэтапное вычисление факториала, в каждом цикле умножая на два числа. минус плюс тоже просто меняется с одного на другой, и своя функция степени на кой нужна?

Comment: Что значит "единственное поэтапное вычисление факториала"? Как это реализовать? Как сделать иначе идею с минус/плюс? Своя функция степени для вычисления степени в числителе, как иначе?

Comment: что-то наподобие такого у вас должно быть вроде https://pastebin.com/Gk8KdSxj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возведение в степень есть в Delphi: System.Math.Power(x,y)
Факториал я бы считал так:

```
function factorial(x:Integer):int64;
var
   i,k:integer;
begin
   k:=1;
   if (x=0) or (x=1) then Result:=1
   else
      for I := 2 to x do
        k:=k*i;
   Result:=k;
end;
```

поскольку рекурсия - излишняя трата времени.

Я понял задачу так: нужно найти сумму сходящегося ряда до O малого < eps. А что у вас ищется в программе - мне не понятно. Схождение суммы ряда проще всего сделать в цикле, запоминая предыдущее значение ряда и сравнивая с текущей, проверяя, попадает ли разница в эпсилон-окрестность. Как-то так:

```
var
  eps,f,f0,y:double;
  x,i:Integer;
  si:Boolean;

    <..>

si:=true; //вначале плюс
i:=-1; // мне удобнее увеличивать счётчик до вычисления члена ряда, поэтому -1
f:=0; // начальное значение ряда
repeat
     inc(i,2); // увеличиваем счётчик на 2
     f0:=f; // запоминаем старое значение суммы ряда
     y:=power(x,i)/factorial(i); // вычисляем новый член
     if si then f:=f + y // тут плюс
     else f:=f - y; // а тут минус
     si:=not si; // меняем знак для следующего члена
until abs(y) < eps; // проверка на эпсилон-окрестность
// поскольку я проверял в консольной программе - у меня Writeln, 
// вы же можете выводить значения на форме
// выводим сумму членов ряда, количество членов, 
// последнее учтенное в сумме слагаемое
Writeln(f,',', (i +1) div 2,',',y );
```

Comment: вместо смены знака проще k =1 и k = -k на каждой итерации. а что касается числителя и знаменателей, то тоже уже написали n(j) = n(j-1)*x^2 и d(j) = d(j-1) *i*(i-1)

Comment: да и разность новой суммы со старой не нужна, она ведь равна посчитанному члену

Comment: При подсчёте результата показывает ошибку: Floating point division by zero

Comment: Если я ввожу x = 2, eps = 0,25, то программа должна вывести сумму 0.9333333, последнее слагаемое 0.2666666, и кол-во слагаемых 3, но выводит ошибку: Floating point division by zero
P.S. все комментарии учёл и перепроверил

Comment: Ещё раз перепроверил. Через Pascal ABC всё отлично работает, а вот в Delphi через формы всё время выдаёт ошибку: Floating point division by zero, хотя я перевёл все переменные в строковый тип

Comment: "хотя я перевёл все переменные в строковый тип" - :((( зачем?

Comment: В самом конце при выводе в текстовое поле формы. Нашёл ошибку: присваивал тип входным данным integer, который округлял eps до нуля. Исправил. Всё отлично работает. Спасибо

Comment: Можете пояснить, почему при высчитывании факториала, рекурсия - лишняя трата времени?

Comment: @kornilovyvan потому, что чем больше N, тем больше вы сделаете вызовов фунции, а это - несколько лишних тактов процессора.

Comment: @teran По коду - меньше, по тактам - больше. Что касается упрощённого решения, то я не стал давать его: во-первых, о нём уже написали, во-вторых, показать некий общий подход в нахождению суммы любого сходящегося ряда, вне зависимости от упрощения вычислений.

Answer (score 1):

Вам не нужно вычислять факториал как таковой. Знаменатель каждого члена - это знаменатель предыдущего, умноженый на два числа. А числитель - числитель предыдущего члена умноженый на икс в квадрате (посчитайте один раз и храните в переменной), то есть степень тоже не нужна.

*Перефразируя капитана Смоллеттa: "Вам вообще ничего нe нужно!" :)*

Comment: таки больше коммент чем ответ.